# Image in listview ordering is not correct and download again

Tags: android, image, listview, android-listview, bitmap

Here is how I set up the list view and how I get the image by downloading it.

Some variable explanation :

The **PostItem** is the model object that contain the data for a listview item

The **ImageLoader** is the async task class to download the image by getting the image url from PostItem

The problem are , the ordering of the image in the listview is incorrect , for example, the image should appear in 1st is appear in both 1st , 4th, and if I scroll , the display pattern change as well.

Also, I find the image are download again if I scroll, even I have check the imageView whether has drawable

Thanks for helping.

====================================================

Here is how I generate the listview:

```
static class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView name;
    TextView date;
    ImageView img;
    TextView msg;
    TextView count;
    ImageView likeBtn;
    ImageView commentBtn;
    ImageView shareBtn;
}

private class MyPostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PostItem> {

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
    }

    public MyPostAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<PostItem> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.postName);
            viewHolder.date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.postDate);
            viewHolder.img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.postImg);
            viewHolder.msg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.postMsg);
            viewHolder.count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.count);
            viewHolder.likeBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
            viewHolder.commentBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.commentBtn);
            viewHolder.shareBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final PostItem post = getItem(position);

        if (post != null) {
            viewHolder.name.setText(post.name);

            try {
                c.setTime(sdf.parse(post.createDate));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            relative_date = DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString (ctx, c.getTimeInMillis() , DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS, 0).toString();
            viewHolder.date.setText(relative_date);

            viewHolder.msg.setText(post.txtMsg);
            viewHolder.count.setText(post.likeCount + " " + getString(R.string.pro_like) + " " + post.commentCount + " " + getString(R.string.reply));

            if (post.isLike) {
                viewHolder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
            } else {
                viewHolder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.before_like);
            }

            if (!post.imageURL.equals("null") && viewHolder.img.getDrawable() == null ) {
                new ImageLoader(ctx).execute(viewHolder.img,Constant.comment_imageFolder + post.imageURL);
            } else {
                viewHolder.img.setImageDrawable(null);
            }

            viewHolder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new APIManager("like", ctx, Constant.likeAPI + "/"
                            + post.commentID + "/" + userID, jsonListener,
                            getResources().getString(R.string.update_data));
                } 
            });

            viewHolder.commentBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ArrayList<PostItem> filterReplyList = new ArrayList<PostItem>();
                    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ReplyActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("commentID", post.commentID);

                    // get reply list
                    for (PostItem reply : replyItemList) {
                        if (reply.postID.equals(post.commentID)
                                || reply.commentID.equals(post.commentID)) {
                            filterReplyList.add(reply);
                        }
                    }
                    i.putExtra("replyItemList", filterReplyList);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                }
            });

            viewHolder.shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    String data = "date: " + post.createDate + "\nmsg:" + post.txtMsg;
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, data);
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    startActivity(sendIntent);
                }
            });

        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

And Here is the imageloader, take the imageview, url as input and put the bitmap in the imageview

```
public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

    private static String TAG = "ImageLoader";
    private InputStream input;
    private ImageView view;
    private ProgressBar loadingIcon;
    private ListView myListView;
    private String imageURL;
    private Context ctx;

    public ImageLoader(Context _ctx) {
        ctx = _ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            view = (ImageView) params[0];

            // handle Chinese characters in file name
//          String[] imgUrlArray = ((String) params[1]).split("/");
//          String fileName = imgUrlArray[imgUrlArray.length - 1];
//          String newfileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "utf-8");
//          imageURL = ((String) params[1]).replace(fileName, newfileName);
            imageURL = ((String) params[1]);

            if (params.length > 2 && (ProgressBar) params[2] != null)
                loadingIcon = (ProgressBar) params[2];

            URL url = new URL(imageURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            input = connection.getInputStream();

            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(input, 4*1024);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte)current);
            }
            byte[] imageData = baf.toByteArray();

            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, options);
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, options);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null && view != null) {
            if (loadingIcon != null)
                loadingIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

**Updated code (implement volley library):**

```
static class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView name;
    TextView date;
    NetworkImageView img;
    TextView msg;
    TextView count;
    ImageView likeBtn;
    ImageView commentBtn;
    ImageView shareBtn;
}

private class MyPostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PostItem> {

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
    }

    public MyPostAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<PostItem> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.postName);
            viewHolder.date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.postDate);
            viewHolder.img = (NetworkImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.postImg);
            viewHolder.msg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.postMsg);
            viewHolder.count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.count);
            viewHolder.likeBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
            viewHolder.commentBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.commentBtn);
            viewHolder.shareBtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final PostItem post = getItem(position);

        if (post != null) {
            viewHolder.name.setText(post.name);

            try {
                c.setTime(sdf.parse(post.createDate));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            relative_date = DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString (ctx, c.getTimeInMillis() , DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS,DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS, 0).toString();
            viewHolder.date.setText(relative_date);

            viewHolder.msg.setText(post.txtMsg);
            viewHolder.count.setText(post.likeCount + " " + getString(R.string.pro_like) + " " + post.commentCount + " " + getString(R.string.reply));

            if (post.isLike) {
                viewHolder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
            } else {
                viewHolder.likeBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.before_like);
            }

            if (!post.imageURL.equals("null")) {
                viewHolder.img.setImageUrl(Constant.comment_imageFolder + post.imageURL, mImageLoader);
            }

            viewHolder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new APIManager("like", ctx, Constant.likeAPI + "/"
                            + post.commentID + "/" + userID, jsonListener,
                            getResources().getString(R.string.update_data));
                } 
            });

            viewHolder.commentBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ArrayList<PostItem> filterReplyList = new ArrayList<PostItem>();
                    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ReplyActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("commentID", post.commentID);

                    // get reply list
                    for (PostItem reply : replyItemList) {
                        if (reply.postID.equals(post.commentID)
                                || reply.commentID.equals(post.commentID)) {
                            filterReplyList.add(reply);
                        }
                    }
                    i.putExtra("replyItemList", filterReplyList);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                }
            });

            viewHolder.shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    String data = "date: " + post.createDate + "\nmsg:" + post.txtMsg;
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, data);
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    startActivity(sendIntent);
                }
            });

        }
        return v;
    }
```

Comment: can you explain what this `!post.imageURL.equals("null") && viewHolder.img.getDrawable() == null ` line of code are supposed to do?

Comment: !post.imageURL.equals("null") means some of the obj has no imageURL so need to check before download, and viewHolder.img.getDrawable() == null means if the view is already has image assigned so no need to download again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the task you are trying to do I would strongly recommend you to use Volley library.

Read from [here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/io-2013/presentations/110%20-%20Volley-%20Easy,%20Fast%20Networking%20for%20Android.pdf)

All you need to do is as below

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new BitmapLruCache());

mImageView.setImageUrl(BASE_URL + item.image_url, mImageLoader);
```

Where `mImageView` is `com.android.volley.NetworkImageView` instead of a regular `ImageView`.

Volley takes care of maintaining the cache and the ordering of the images.

Comment: You need to provide an implementation of this cache something like this

     public class BitmapLruCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap>   implements ImageCache {
   //Override the methods here 
}

Comment: Thanks , I implemented it , very great library, it loads much faster than my own written calss, but the image display still the same,eg. 1st pic is show in the 4th listview row, any idea on fixing it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you scroll the listview you will get back recycled `convertview`, it is not null but it has incorrect imageview. `convertView` is a view thats created and recycled through scrolling the list. this view makes GC be called less and also save memory for you. it first assigned by your earliest items of list. after you scroll the list, for example item one of list disappears and you see item 15 the convertView of item one is passed again to you. in this time it is not null  and it holdes the reference of last imageview, the imageview of item 1.

so this is your problem, you skipped assigning correct imageview to your `viewHolder.img`.
Ok, what should you do? 
the best thing you can do is create in memory cache that holds your downloaded imageview by their URLs as  keys of the cache. in getview you check the cache, if it has your URL of current imageview position read from it and set it to `viewHolder.img` else download the image from internet.

Golden rule is:

```
   ALWAYS OVERWRITE VIEWHOLDER VALUES WITH VALUES OF YOUR ITEM AT INDEX POSITON THAT

   GETVIEW PASSES TO YOU
```

how to create cache? look at `Example LRU cache` at

http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html

and if you want you can also use volley library instead.

Comment: I have implemented volley lib but the order problem seems not fixed, any idea? thanks

Comment: @user782104 post your getView that you use volley in it!!

Comment: sorry I am afraid I confused, the getView used  viewHolder.img.setImageUrl(Constant.comment_imageFolder + post.imageURL, mImageLoader); to get the image

Comment: update volley library code in your getview . i will be back in 15 mins

Comment: what else I need besides this download image code ? Thanks

Comment: refer to user @Ajit, I changed the imageView to NetworkImageView and download it his reference code, are there anything else I need?

Comment: I am going home now , take around 1 hour , may discuss later, thanks for your help

Comment: ok you still have problem, yes? `eg. 1st pic is show in the 4th listview row`

Comment: if you solved your issues let me know the solution else i have some ideas !!

Comment: @user782104 first i do not think your program has any problem and i think this happens because the image has not completely downloaded from internet.In order to confirm this you can scroll the list and stop it suddenly to see if wrong images replace by correct one or not

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!post.imageURL.equals("null") && viewHolder.img.getDrawable() == null ) {
                new ImageLoader(ctx).execute(viewHolder.img,Constant.comment_imageFolder + post.imageURL);
}
```

I am guessing that the problem lies here. What happens when you get a recycled view which already has an image from the previous view it was used for? That explains why the image appears in both 1st and 4th position and the change in the display pattern when you scroll.

Get the point? Remove the `viewHolder.img.getDrawable() == null` and try. See if that helps.

Comment: @user782104 Okay, explain this: `Constant.comment_imageFolder + post.imageURL` Why are you using the `+` ?

Comment: post.imageURL is the image name , and Constant.comment_imageFolder is the domain name e.g. "http://mydomain/img" + "1.jpg" Thanks.